Can I rebase a sub-tree of a repository?
We have a frontend and a backend folder in our master branch in github. I need to get the latest changes from only the backend folder and rebase it with my feature branch. I am not sure how accomplish this.
This is what I currently do:
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git checkout new-section
git rebase master
git pull --rebase origin new-section

If any push you need to do means, do , or resolve merge conflicts
this is what i'm doing in my daily routine,
when i rebase , all commits from master will apply to my branch front end too, so what to do?

Hi, Pavithra. Welcome to StackOverflow. You need to put some more effort into your post, but this is only to make it easier to help you. It is currently unclear what you mean by "If any push you need to do means, do , or resolve merge conflicts", as this is not a grammatically correct sentence and I don't understand what you are trying to say.

Generally, you cannot selectively rebase just a sub-folder. It's all or nothing. It would on the other hand be very helpful for us if you elaborate WHAT you are really trying to accomplish. Why can you not have changes to the frontend folder? What you are trying to do will result in data loss, no matter what, and in 15 years of software development I have not a single case where this makes sense, so try to enlighten us. If you are trying to avoid conflicts with your frontend changes, then sorry: you must resolve those conflicts if you rebase, but maybe there is a way for us to help you :)

Does this answer your question? Rebase only a single folder
